# Is there an option to configure mapstructs source property null checks?

Tags: java, spring, mapping, mapstruct

I am trying to map information from two objects into one object.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public abstract class FooMapper {

    // some @Mapping-Annotations
    public abstract TargetObject map(ObjectA a, ObjectB b);

}
```

Mapstruct generates something like this:

```
@Component
public class FooMapperImpl extends FooMapper {

    @Override
    public TargetObject map(ObjectA a, ObjectB b) {
        if ( a == null && b== null ) {
            return null;
        }

        // rest of the code

    }

}
```

So in order to recieve *null* as a result from the map function, **a and b** have to be *null*. In my case I also want *null* to be returned if **just a** (regardless of b) is *null*. And I am pretty sure there might also be usecases, where one want *null* to be returned as soon as **at least one** source object is *null*.

Is there any way to configure the mapper, the method or annotate the source object(s) for a behaviour like this?

I already tried to configure a *nullValueMappingStrategy* and a *nullValueCheckStrategy* to the @Mapper- and/or the @Mapping-Annotations. But with these strategies I was not able to split the null checks of the source objects.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this, you can add default method in your mapper as:

```
default TargetObject map(ObjectA a, ObjectB b){
     if ( a == null || b== null ) {
            return null;
     }else{
        // do your stuff..
     }
 }
```